# Reusing ANTLR3 lexer and parser

Tags: c, antlr3

I create an input stream from a string with

```
pANTLR3_UINT8 input_string = (pANTLR3_UINT8) "test";
pANTLR3_INPUT_STREAM stream = antlr3StringStreamNew(input_string, ANTLR3_ENC_8BIT, sizeof(input_string), (pANTLR3_UINT8)"testname");
```

and then use my lexer and parser to process the string. When I'm done with this string I want to process a new one, but re-creating the lexer and parser objects seems inefficient.

I've found the `reset` method of the lexer and parser classes and the `reuse` method of the stream, but how do I use those to parse a new string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the [`setCharStream()`](http://www.antlr.org/api/C/antlr3lexer_8c.html#3f121d133cb810a9687aee3089e33be8) function.

Comment: Do I also need to call reset on the lexer/parser/stream? Would you mind providing a short example?

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `reset()` manually; the [C version](http://www.antlr.org/depot/antlr3/release-3.1.3/runtime/C/src/antlr3lexer.c) resets most of the internal variables (and comments near calls to `setCharStream()` mention resetting the state). (The [Java version](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/_lexer_8java-source.html#l00123) calls `reset()` explicitly, too.) You should just be able to create a new `pANTLR3_INPUT_STREAM` for your new stream and reset with `setCharStream(lexer, new_stream)`, constructing the stream as you've already done.